# Two ManyToMany relations to the same model via the same intermediate model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.11

My models:

```
class Person(SchoolModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    last_surname = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    students = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='StudentParent',
        through_fields=('parent', 'student'), related_name='+')
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='StudentParent',
        through_fields=('student', 'parent'), related_name='+')


class StudentParent(SchoolModel):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    relation = models.CharField(max_length=26)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('student', 'parent')
```

As seen above Person model has two m2m relationships to itself: students, and parents. Each person may have many students on the same Person table, and also many parents.

However, Django does not allow this:

```
Person: (models.E003) The model has two many-to-many relations through  
the intermediate model 'StudentParent'.
```

I don't see why Django refuses to do so especially since it does not save or validate m2m fields with custom intermediary tables.  On the other hand, I only need to use these fields to retrieve related models more easily. Examples:

```
person_obj.students.all()
Person.objects.filter(parents__in=another_person_queryset)
```

So my question is, 1) Is there a way around this issue in Django1.11 (making such 2 m2m fields possible via configuration etc)? 
2) is there a way to make this happen for a read only scenario by other means?

Would using a proxy to the intermediary model trick django to make 1) happen?
Would using custom managers help make 2) happen? What would be the shortest, neatest path?

*Note:* I am aware a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436362/django-model-has-two-manytomany-relations-through-intermediate-model) is asked before, however that is a little different and a little old.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Why can't you use just `students` with `parents` as the `related_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems tricking Django via a proxy model works for the purposes I described above (retrieving related data of model instances or within filtering querysets). So the models become:

```
class Person(SchoolModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    last_surname = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    students = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='StudentParentProxy', # << !!!!!!
        through_fields=('parent', 'student'), related_name='+')
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='StudentParent',
        through_fields=('student', 'parent'), related_name='+')


class StudentParent(SchoolModel):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    relation = models.CharField(max_length=26)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('student', 'parent')


class StudentParentProxy(StudentParent):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True  # << !!!!!!
```