# create ManyToManyField using field in through table as condition

Tags: python, django, join, manytomanyfield

This is what I want to achieve:

```
class Event(Model):
    attendees = ManyToManyField(User, through='Involvement', related_name='attended_events')
    interested_users = ManyToManyField(User, through='Involvement', related_name='interested_in_events')
    organizers = ManyToManyField(User, through='Involvement', related_name='organized_events')

class Involvement(Model):
    event = ForeignKey(Event, CASCADE)
    user = ForeignKey(User, CASCADE)
    involvement = CharField(choices=(('INTERESTED', 'Interested'), ('ATTENDED', 'Attended'), ('ORGANIZED', 'Organized')))
```

The error I'm receiving:

```
 The model has three identical many-to-many relations through the intermediate model 'app.ActivityInvolvement'.
```

I know `limit_choices_to` doesn't work on ManyToManyField, how would I go about making this happen, without creating 3 through tables with the same structure?

Comment: Why do you need through tables at all? Why not have three completely separate m2m fields?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26436863/1339013) may help.