# Django: The model has two identical many-to-many relations through the intermediate model

Tags: python, django

I have seen this question: [The model has two many-to-many relations through the intermediate model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569035/the-model-has-two-many-to-many-relations-through-the-intermediate-model)

But I think my problem is slightly different:

```
class Building(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    prices = models.ManyToManyField('Resource',
                                    through='BuildingResourceRelation',
                                    related_name="prices")
    outputs = models.ManyToManyField('Resource',
                                     through='BuildingResourceRelation',
                                     related_name="outputs")
    inputs = models.ManyToManyField('Resource',
                                    through='BuildingResourceRelation',
                                    related_name="inputs")

class Resource(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class BuildingResourceRelation(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey('Building', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resource = models.ForeignKey('Resource', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

According to design there can be a different amount of prices, inputs, and outputs.

I can create through model for each, but isn't there a better way?